# Connect to one server, and from there connect to another to read file

Tags: vb.net, remote-access, remote-server

My problem is I basically need to on command, connect to one server, and from there connect to another (both of which I have access to). I need to connect to the first to reach the second. And on the second I need to read something from a text file. And fire that information back.

Is that possible? I wouldn't even know where to start. I'm fine with the text file thing!

Help would be appreciated.

EDIT - neither server is connected to the inter-web : (.

Comment: Have you thought about writing a web service for the first server that will connect to the second server?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do something like a Service or Web Service on both of them so you can communicate with them and allow them to do some work.